# Setting up limits for a double integral over a triangle.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to integrate $\int \int_{D_2} f(x, y) \,dx \,dy$ where $D_2$ is pictured below.

[image]

I thought it would be $\int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x, y) \, dx \, dy$ but that's wrong. But why? I thought when we're integrating with respect to $x$ first we fix $y$ in the inner limits: when $y = 0$ we have $x = 0$  and when $y = 1$ we have $x = y$.

Comment: Your formula makes reference to the triangle where $0 \le x \le y$. Now, the triangle in the picture is in the half plane where $y \le x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off your last paragraph, you might get a good indicator as to what's going on when $y = 1$. You are right that you integrate to $x = y$. But in particular, you integrate $x$ from $0$ to $y$.

So when $y = 1$, you are integrating all $x$ from $0$ to $1$. And in particular, you are integrating over a region containing the line from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$. Notice that this is the wrong triangle!

You have flipped up your $x$s and $y$s in your integrals.